# Обрезать нижнюю часть блока

Tags: css

Есть блок определенной высоты. Как мне обрезать нижнюю часть блока на 50px (содержимое блока, которое входит в эти 50px, должно быть обрезано)? Возможно как-то затенить нижнюю часть блока или еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите наглядный пример.

Comment: Да просто обрезать низ блока на 50px. Зачем пример?

Comment: Пример для того, чтобы люди поняли что вы имеете ввиду под словом "обрезать"

Comment: Покажите код на jsfiddle